# How can I get the record which its value is the maximum

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table contains a column with Date datatype. I want to get the record which its date value is the maximum.

Linq supports `Max`, but it returns the value itself. I want the record which its value is the maximum.

Any help!

Comment: Put some effort for framing the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `Records` is a collection of your object and the column/property to get the max of is called `value`:

```
var q = Records.OrderByDescending(p => p.value)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I was trying with `OrderBy` + `LastOrDefault` which throwed an exception. this is perfect. thanks.

Comment: @John - no problem. `Last` and `LastOrDefault` are not supported to L2E as far as I am aware

Answer (score 2):

You can order the collection by date and select the first one:

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
records.OrderByDescending(record => record.Date).First();
```

You could use `FirstOrDefault()` to not throw an Exception when the collection is empty (`null` is returned)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately LINQ doesn't have a `MaxBy` operator. You probably need to order your items descending by the appropriate property, and then take the first value:

```
Customer lastRegistered = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(x => x.RegistrationDate)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Hopefully SQL Server can work out how to do that without *really* doing a full sort :)

In LINQ to Objects it's relatively easy to write a `MaxBy` method of course - I've got on in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "record" is referring to a record from a table in an underlying database that can handle the resulting SQL efficiently (and supports the max aggregate):

```
var q = 
    from t in thetable where t.Date == thetable.Max( d => d.Date ) select t;
```

That would find records matching the maximum date.  `First()` could be used to grab just one.

Comment: Dont't this make two round trips ?

Comment: @John: It probably depends on the underlying database (and the provider implementation), but it results in a single SQL SELECT statement.  In most cases, though, I believe it should be a single trip.